# Python- How to form a random partition of 2 lists

Tags: python, list, random, partition

Does anyone know how to form a random partition of 2 lists (List1 and List2) in python? The lists do not have to have the same size.
For example:

```
S = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
List1=[3,6,1,2]
List2=[5,4,7]
```

or

```
List1 =[3,5]
List2=[1,2,4,7,6]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi. I have not. I'm very new to Python. I am trying to form a random initial solution for solving  minimum cut problem using simulated annealing.

Comment: Sorry, we are not here to write code for you or give you a personal training. Please try something first, read tutorials etc... and come back when you have so code to show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what your rules are around randomness and partitioning, but this should get you started:

```
import random

s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

random.shuffle(s)

cut = random.randint(0, len(s))
list_1 = s[:cut]
list_2 = s[cut:]

print list_1
print list_2
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend:

1. Shuffle or randomly rearrange the list
2. Then choose the random index at which to break up the list

Code:

```
import random

S = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
random.shuffle(S)
index = random.randint(0, len(S))
List1 = S[index:]
List2 = S[:index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what modules you have but this is a function that does what you want.

```
import random
def split(S): 
    x = random.randint(0,len(S))
    y = len(S)-x
    S1 = S[0:x]
    S2 = []
    for i in range(len(S)):
        if S[i] not in S1:
           S2.append(S[i])
    return S1,S2
```

Comment: thank you!! Do you know how to modify the code if I want the first element is always in list 1 and the last element is always in list 2?