# How to get the remaining sample after using random.sample() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, sample

I have a large list of elements (in this example I'll assume it's filled with numbers). For example: `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
 Now I want to take 2 samples from that list, one with the 80% of the elements (randomly chosen of course), and the other one with the remaining elements (the 20%), so I can use the bigger one to train a machine-learning tool, and the rest to test that training. The function I used is from `random` and I used it this way:

```
sz = len(l) #Size of the original list
per = int((80 * sz) / 100) #This will be the length of the sample list with the 80% of the elements (I guess)
random.seed(1) # As I want to obtain the same results every time I run it.
l2 = random.sample(l, per)
```

I'm not totally sure, but I believe that with that code I'm getting a random sample with the 80% of the numbers.

```
l2 = [3,4,7,2,9,5,1,8]
```

Nonetheless, I can't seem to find the way to get the other sample list with the remaining elements `l3 = [6,10]` (the `sample()` function does not remove the elements it takes from the original list). Can you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've tagged this machine-learning. Your machine learning library probably includes a train-test split function already.

Comment: One such option: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: Also check out the answer here if you wish to go with random: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196649/python-how-to-form-a-random-partition-of-2-lists

Comment: If they have unique values then `set(l)-set(l2)`

Comment: @Maria thank you! that sci-kit function helped me a lot, as that is the tool I'm using for machine learning ;)

Answer (score 2):

For me the following code worked to randomly split a list into two (training/testing) sets, even though most machine learning libraries include easy to use splitting functions as mentioned before:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
sz = len(l)
cut = int(0.8 * sz) #80% of the list
shuffled_l = random.shuffle(l)
l2 = shuffled_l[:cut] # first 80% of shuffled list
l3 = shuffled_l[cut:] # last 20% of shuffled list
```

Comment: According to the docs, random.shuffle will ```Shuffle the sequence x in place. ... To shuffle an immutable sequence and return a new shuffled list, use sample(x, k=len(x)) instead.``` - [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) So either call shuffle on l and use l for the cut, or if you want a new list use sample. Code as written will not work, shuffled_l is None

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
from random import sample

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

training = sample(a, len(data)*cut)

testing = [value for value in data if value not in training]
```